# PHPExcel set setRowHeight(-1) and setWrapText(true) not automatically resizing height of the row

Tags: php, excel

Have tried the following, it didn't help, what should I try next? Anything I have missed?

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A10', 'Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(10)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A10')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

Then

```
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
foreach($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rd) { 
    $rd->setRowHeight(-1); 
}
```

Also

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getStyle('A1:D10')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(2)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(3)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(4)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(5)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(6)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(7)->setRowHeight(-1);
```

Comment: An update. This works when I open the file in google sheet and MS Office Excel and not when I open it in LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is known bug of LibreOffice:

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62268

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/588